# Array sorting for Object Keys not working

Tags: javascript

Could someone please help me sort object by key with given array?

`given array ['NAME',20200229,20200131,20200331]`

`given object {20200131: 51, 20200229: 50, 20200331: 170, NAME: "a"}`

`Object.fromEntries` was expected to build object in the given keys

```
Object.fromEntries(Object.entries({b: 3, a:8, c:1}))
//{b: 3, a: 8, c: 1}  <-- works fine
```

But when I try with keys that has number and alphanumerics it's doesn't work

```
let sortingArr = ['NAME',20200229,20200131,20200331]  // desired sort, for example
// All below gives the same result
Object.fromEntries(Object.entries({NAME: 'a',20200131: 51, 20200229: 50, 20200331: 170})) 
// sort asc naturally,.. ok
Object.fromEntries(Object.entries({NAME: 'a',20200131: 51, 20200229: 50, 20200331: 170}).sort()) 
// sort asc naturally,.. redundant... ok, no problems
Object.fromEntries(Object.entries({NAME: 'a',20200131: 51, 20200229: 50, 20200331: 170}).sort((a, b)=> parseInt(a)||0 + sortingArr.indexOf(b)))
//Problem! was supose to consider the sorting logic*, right?

//*Sorting works: Object.entries({NAME: 'a',20200131: 51, 20200229: 50, 20200331: 170}).sort((a, b)=> parseInt(a)||0 + sortingArr.indexOf(b)) 
//0: ["NAME", "a"]
//1: ["20200131", 51]
//2: ["20200229", 50]
//3: ["20200331", 170]
```

I read other responses and they are very redundant, with people wanting only in ascending (or descending) order, without the desired array

Comment: If you read other posts on this topic, you should've come across the realisation that objects are inherently unordered and you should not be trying to sort them.

Comment: Ok! =), but it's confunsing with people telling it's unordered and then right after giving some method

Comment: Now I am working with array instead. Thanks!